# What are the keys contained in request.POST.has_key(*...*)?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I was going through source code of one of the django applications in my organisation. I can see `response_add` method overridden in `admin.py` as below :

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if '_upload' in request.POST:
         url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (
          self.model._meta.app_label,
          self.model._meta.model_name), args=[obj.pk],
          current_app=self.admin_site.name)
         return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
         return super(DfInpAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

I cant find anywhere on internet what is `_upload` here. ?
Instead I see many code snippets with `if request.POST.has_key("_popup"):`.

What are these `_upload`, `_popup`, `_continue` ?
Are they django provided or custom defined in some other .py of my source code?

Comment: Confusing question. This has nothing to do with anything defined in any .py files. Surely you know that `request.POST` is a dictionary of the data posted from the browser?

Comment: Yes. What I dont know is , what is _upload ? i dont have any attribute 'upload' in my models.py ?

Comment: ... it's a field in the data that is posted from your browser...

Comment: Sorry Daniel, i am not able to get you. There is no 'upload' field in the respective models.py

Comment: I didn't say anything about the model. It's in the template, probably a submit button.